# Activity not found android

Tags: java, android

So i want to make a floating app which on click would stop location.
here's the MainActivity class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Service {

private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead;



@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    chatHead.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);

    chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float initialTouchX;
        private float initialTouchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    chatHead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,LocationService.class);
            startService(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}



@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

In the manifest i have set the MainActivity as a service. now when i try to run the app it shows an error

Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found

What is the issue here? i mean i know there is no activity and i intend to have no activity because it is a service ( a floating app).
What to do

----------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------
Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <service
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </service>
    <service android:name=".LocationService"/>

</application>
```

Comment: Services don't have a ui. Post your manifest for further clarification

Comment: yeah just updated the post.

Comment: @VivekMishra I updated the theme to

        android:theme="@style/Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton"
it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is that you need to start the service from some activity. Service will not be started automatically. To start the service create an activity. Lets say Activity A. Now in its layout lets say there is a button. 
on click of button you need to start your service using startService(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class))

Now A should be declared in manifest as launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have application without launcher activity!!!
Because it needs a way to start your service..and here it does not have one..
Also you can not use any type of broadcast receiver like BOOT_COMPELETED to start your service  because starting from android 3.0 your application should be launched at least once to receive any broadcast like that..
So it would be better if you have one launcher activity although u didn't require it..you can just start your service from that activity and finish it..
And as soon as your service starts you will have your chathead ready!!